# How many many steps needed for n*n matrix multiplication?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, multiplication, calculation, problem-steps-recorder

I have got a strange question in previous year question and that is , if an algorithm needs 21 steps for a 7*7 matrix multiplication then how many steps would it need for n*n matrix multiplication ?

I have tried to do 7*7 matrix multiplication and calculated how many multiplications done . Then I tried to relate the n of multiplications with the steps . But it does not work .

From many people , I have heard that the answer is 3n but they cannot explain the cause of being 3n as the answer .

Can you simply give me an idea how can I solve this question ?

Comment: Looks more like *(n-1) n/2*.

Comment: Explain logic of  your solution

Comment: Well you enumerate over a triangle of elements, so that requires (n-1) n/2 steps.

Comment: Can you post as a answer explaining details ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that for each row.dot(column) you have to do the same thing, and you have to do this for each row.column pair - so it seems like each dimension would give you `21/7=3` steps, since you have 7 row.column pairs needing a total of 21 steps.